# Android Push Notifications - Parse.com API - Not working?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Here is the application code:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.UI.MainActivity;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;
import com.parse.PushService;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;



public class GhostChatApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "P0zIagKQvEGdopuoLZuucgzC7H4oz64U7GZkGe1n", "mT15MV8OFEMTDNQaGU5XdLHTXMsNxnUxJdXVp4O3");    
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    }

}
```

Although subscribing to the channel wasn't mentioned in Docs, but when I tested, I did successfully subscribe. If I put some random string in it wouldn't work so probably "testNotification" happens to be correct.
Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".GhostChatApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.UI.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I removed the application tags to make the code small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `<service>` and `<receiver>` tags must be inside `<application></application>` exactly like the `<activity>` not outside so insert them inside

```
<application
    android:name=".GhostChatApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.UI.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

and remove them from any other place outside